# How to get center of gravity coordinates of a robot?

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Can anyone tell me how to get center of gravity coordinates of a robot in gazebo?
I'm controlling 10DOF robot and would like to see the CoG trajectory as the robot moves.
I found "getcog" in the API, but don't know how to use it.
Please share some nice ways to do this. Thank you.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/5758/how-to-get-center-of-gravity-coordinates-of-a-robot?/) by [Wonyoung](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/279/wonyoung/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 37 on 2014-03-28

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

There is no convenience function to get the CoG of a whole robot. You'll have to iterate over all the links in the robot, get the CoG, and compute the overall CoG.

[Get all links in a model](http://gazebosim.org/api/dev/classgazebo_1_1physics_1_1Model.html#ae5db568f6f71777b45c36fdcb427956e)

[Get the interial properties of a link](http://gazebosim.org/api/dev/classgazebo_1_1physics_1_1Link.html#a1f1f68da2f18d386111a7521c9aebcf1)

[Get the CoG](http://gazebosim.org/api/dev/classgazebo_1_1physics_1_1Inertial.html#a6388ffbd1a49f64156209463c5fa2f8e)

---

Originally posted by [nkoenig](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/5/nkoenig/) with karma: 7676 on 2014-03-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Wonyoung](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/279/wonyoung/) on 2014-03-31**:
Thank you for the answer!